# MongoDB Descending order query considerably slower than Ascending

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with around 60 million documents in it, essentially log entries (userid, date, log).

There is an index on userid - and a query to get all logs for a specific user takes milliseconds (in the example I have, it returns around 45,000 documents).

If I try and return the latest 20 documents - by sort descending by date, the query can take up to 10 seconds.  (in fact, return *all* documents descending is considerably slower)

I tried a wider index for userid and date(descending), however it's not made any difference.

Is there a way to speed this query up?

Comment: Add query plans with execution stats to the question.